# Homeomorphism Dihedral Group to Group of Rotation/Permutation Matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, dihedral-groups

This question is quite direct, but I guess I might be falling in redundancy.

Prove that there is only 1 homeomorphism $h: D_{2n}\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, such that:

$h(r)=$ rotation matrix with angle $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$

$h(s)=$ permutation matrix

My idea is to assume there are two homeomorphism, but when I conclude that both are equal it seems that I'm saying something that I assumed previously. What should I add, or how would you aproach the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t “homomorphism”? A “**homeomorphism**” is a continuous function with continuous inverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case my comment is correct, let $\varphi$ be one such homomorphism. Suppose $\psi$ is also a homomorphism with the required property.

Since $D_{2n}$ is generated by $r, s$ - i.e. every element is of the form $s^lr^k$, where $l \in \{0, 1\}$ and $k \in \{0, …, n - 1\}$ — and $\psi(s^lr^k) = \psi(s^l) \psi(r^k) = \psi(s)^l \psi(r)^k$, which in turn equals $ \varphi(s)^l \varphi(r)^k = \varphi(s^lr^k)$, we conclude that $\psi = \varphi$, since they coincide in every element of $D_{2n}$.

Notice how, in this proof, I assumed there are two and proved they are equal. I haven’t used any of the thesis in my proof - if you did something similar, you’re probably good to go.

Also notice, as pointed out in the comments, that I used as a **hypothesis** that there is one. So you would also have to show that the function $\varphi: D_{2n} \to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ that maps
$$r \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{n}) & -\sin(\frac{2 \pi}{n}) \\ \sin(\frac{2 \pi}{n}) & \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{n}) \end{bmatrix}$$
$$s \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
is a homomorphism, when extended to the entirety of $D_{2n}$, to show one exists.

Does that make sense?

Comment: You've proved that there is at most one. You should probably, for completeness, also prove that there's at least one by exhibiting it. You also haven't *quite* answered OP's question ("What should I add?"), and your solution to "How would you approach the problem?" is basically to give the proof that OP seems to already have.